# HiveCli - SessionHiveMetaStoreClient Connection is already closed

Tags: hadoop, hive

while running hive I am getting following error.

```
>C:\HIVE\bin>hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/HIVE/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Beeline version 2.1.0 by Apache Hive
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Connection is already closed.
```

Comment: Sounds like you have not started the server, so there's nothing to connect to locally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you haven't started the *Metastore service* so you have to start it using these commands:

```
hive --service metastore &
hive --service hiveserver2 &
```

Hive Session IDs will be generated and you can write **jps** to check that 2 Run Jars are running as Java services.